# Grouping by 0.005 miles buckets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with that looks like the following:

| index | trip_id | distance |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 0.000 |  |  |
| 1 | 3 | 0.004 |  |  |
| 2 | 4 | 0.487 |  |  |
| 4 | 5 | 0.268 |  |  |
| 5 | 66 | 0.000 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

I would like for the output to look like this:

| Mileage | Count of Trips |
| --- | --- |
| 0-0.001 |  |
| 0.002-0.005 |  |
| 0.006-0.010 |  |
| 0.011-0.025 |  |
| … |  |
| 4.996-5 |  |

I want to first create these groups and then I want to count the number of trips in each groups.

I know how to do this with time using resample but how can I do this with distance?

Comment: why is the first level "0-0.001" and not "0-0.005"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
        dataset = [
            [0, 2, 0.000],
            [1, 3, 0.004],
            [2, 4, 0.487],
            [4, 5, 0.268],
            [5, 66, 0.000],
        ]
        mileage = [0, 0.001, 0.005, 0.010, 0.025, 0.25, 0.30, 0.50, 4.995, 5]
        groups = []
        uniquekeys = []
        bucket_distance = lambda row:bisect.bisect_left(mileage, row[2])
        data = sorted(dataset, key=bucket_distance)
        for k, g in groupby(data, bucket_distance):
            groups.append(list(g))
            uniquekeys.append(k)
        print(groups)
        print(uniquekeys)
        mileage_counts = Counter()
        for x in dataset:
            mileage_counts[bucket_distance(x)] += 1

        print(f"{'Mileage' : <24}Count of Trips")
        [print(f"{mileage[i] : <10}{'to' : <4}{mileage[i + 1] : <10}{mileage_counts[i] : <4}") for i in uniquekeys]

        print(f"{'Mileage' : <24}Count of Trips")
        [print(f"{mileage[i] : <10}{'to' : <4}{mileage[i + 1] : <10}{mileage_counts[i] : <4}") for i in range(len(mileage) - 1)]
```

It gives the following output:

```
[[[0, 2, 0.0], [5, 66, 0.0]], [[1, 3, 0.004]], [[4, 5, 0.268]], [[2, 4, 0.487]]]
[0, 2, 6, 7]
Mileage                 Count of Trips
0         to  0.001     2   
0.005     to  0.01      1   
0.3       to  0.5       1   
0.5       to  4.995     1   
Mileage                 Count of Trips
0         to  0.001     2   
0.001     to  0.005     0   
0.005     to  0.01      1   
0.01      to  0.025     0   
0.025     to  0.25      0   
0.25      to  0.3       0   
0.3       to  0.5       1   
0.5       to  4.995     1   
4.995     to  5         0
```